# Check if digits in a number can be rearranged to form a fibonacci number

Tags: string, algorithm, fibonacci

This question is asked in a programming contest. I couldn't find any way other than generating all permutations. But the number of digits is upto 15 and no of permutations (15!) is very large. Is there any other way?

I know that if (5*N^2 + 4) or (5*N^2 - 4) is a perfect square, n is fibonacci.

Comment: As an aside, assuming you work in base-10, there are far fewer than 15! permutations of any 15-digit number.

Comment: Yes. 15! divided the product of the factorial of the no of repeating numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to generate all permutations. Generate the fibonacci numbers of desired length (which will be less than 74 numbers, because 73rd fib. number is the highest with 15 digits) and then just check for those few whether they can be "constructed" from digits in the given number.

Comment: I didn't know that Fibonacci sequence increases so drastically. Exponential growth I think. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, inverting the direction can make for a surprising jump in efficiency.

Comment: Upvoted. As a note, the fibonacci numbers grow at a rate of phi (~= 1.618). Since phi**5 > 10, there can never be more than 5 Fibonacci numbers with the same digit length (except for digit length 1).